# using comparison with char

Tags: c++, char

I need help figuring out what i am doing wrong here. I am trying to get the user to enter one of two option (y or n)and will keep asking until they choose one of the right option, but when i run it and and enter n to exit the loops it stays stuck inside the second while loop i do not know what i am doing wrong

```
char dec;
dec = 'y';
while(dec=='y')
        {
cout<<"would you like to ente an option?(y/n)"<<endl;
            cin>>dec;

            while((dec != 'y')||(dec != 'n'))
            {
                cout<<"you entered an invalid option please try again"<<endl;
                cin>>dec;
                    }       


        }
```

Comment: That `||` has to be an `&&`. At least one of both is always true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `while` condition. When `dec == 'n'`, `dec != 'y'` is true and you are inside the loop. Just change the condtion:

```
while  (dec != 'y' && dec != 'n')
```